# Do I need identical servers for load balancing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am new to using AWS and web hosting in general.
Let's say I currently have a single server running a website, and the traffic starts to grow to a point I need to use load balancing.
Assuming my current server is running on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu, and an Apache server with all the website files inside the `/var/www/` folder. If I want to add load balancing, do I need to create an EC2 instance with the same website files copied to it? Or I just need to create an empty EC2 instance and the rest is done automatically? A bit confused as to how it would work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need to create an identical (in configuration only) ec2 instance which contains the same files in `/var/www` as the main instance and when you make changes, you have to make sure that the changes are applied in both servers.

I think the best method to keep both server site configuration identical is to set-up a git repository which contains all your site files, and clone it in both servers in addition to setting a cron job which will run `git pull` every hour or so.

Another thing you can do, is to create an Elastic File System and mount it in both servers. Info about this process can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-getting-started.html).

Comment: *"The load balancer will know which server and port to send the request to based on cpu / networking stats"*  ...I don't believe CPU/networking stats are ever considered by any AWS load balancer.  Can you cite a source for this assertion?

Comment: You're right, with the configuration at hand, there cannot be load balancing based on stats. It is doable though using an alb with a target group attached to an auto-scaling group configured with scaling policies. I've edited my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Each server needs all the content, and you need to set up the server and content. It's not automatic.

Options for keeping content in sync between the servers:

- Version control (git is pretty standard)
- Golden AMI (though this means every code change means replacing all your servers)
- Use Amazon Elastic File System to host the code / resource (consider latency)
- rsync (some content may be stale)

You may also need to consider where the database lives. AWS RDS is a good option in many cases. You can of course continue to use one server as the database server, or even cluster the database servers, but RDS is easy and scales (manually).

Your servers within the cluster should be the same size as traffic is distributed to them equally. You could probably use ALB to send specific traffic to specific servers, doing a kind of manual load balance, but this doesn't give you any redundancy.

You should look at auto scaling. This will run the number of servers you need for the current load. With this scenario you're often better off with more, smaller servers rather than a small number of large servers, to give finer grained control of the server required. For this to work you need good automation, such as an AMI that has all your software on it and ideally reasonably recent code. When the server boot you can have the code updated.